# Is there any way in Swift 3 to update a Dictionary key value and get the previous value in one operation?

Tags: swift

Apple's docs state that the return value of the subscript operation is "The value associated with key if key is in the dictionary; otherwise, nil," but it seems that this must not apply to cases where there is a "set" done.

The following code gives an error "previousValue" cannot be nil.

```
let previousValue = data[key] = key;
if (previousValue != nil)
```

I have replaced this with

```
let previousValue = data[key];
data[key] = key;
```

but I would like to do it more efficiently if possible.

Comment: [`func updateValue(_ value: Dictionary.Value, forKey key: Dictionary.Key) -> Dictionary.Value?`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary/1539001-updatevalue). Note the optional return (as a value for a given key does not necessarily exist).

Comment: @matt I've earned a "Popular Question" badge for this question as it has reached over 1,000 views! Your sarcastic comment and downvote do not seem appropriate.

Comment: @matt Sarcasm is unhelpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let previousValue = data.updateValue(newValue, forKey: key)
```

Answer (score 1):

considering the constant and dictionary already exist, you could only:

```
dictionaryName.updateValue("Old Value", forKey: "Dictionary Key")
```

Hope it helps others! :)